Is it possible to convert html file to pdf without damaging its appearance?
I have a html file and size is about 110 Mb. I want to convert it to a PDF so I can print it.
I opened that html file in Mozilla and saved it as PDF file (CTRL + P and I got Print window). When I open that PDF file, it's text is damaged (hardly readable) on lot of places.

Is there any solution?
Is it possible to convert html do PDF without damaging its content?

I also tried few software (iPubsoft HTML to PDF Converter) and I had exactly same problem like when I tried to save that html file as PDF.

If you know how to use react, you can use the react-to-print library, it will allow you to open the print table and print the html template as pdf or print directly. As for pure js, you can learn some other print libraries like Print.js (you can try)
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
        content: () => componentRef?.current,
        documentTitle: 'title',
    });

